# Cannot browse network via Windows Explorer but cmd works

Tags: windows-7, networking

I seem to have changed something on my system so I can't browse network locations in explorer reliably but I **can** connect via CMD (eg. dir \net01\share1) or within applications or other protocols, SVN server, etc.

When I browse to "\net01\share1" in explorer I get an error:

```
[Window Title]
Network Error

[Main Instruction]
Windows cannot access \\net01\share1

[Content]
Check the spelling of the name. Otherwise, there might be a problem with your network.
To try to identify and resolve network problems, click Diagnose.

[^] Hide details  [Diagnose] [Cancel]

[Expanded Information]
Error code: 0x80004005
Unspecified error
```

What's odd is the error is always the same whether it's a real server or a made up name.
I can't even connect to my own machine from itself. If I click on the icon in Network I get this error:

```
[Window Title]
Open Folder

[Content]
\\WINSEVENPRO is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network
resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access 
permissions.

The specified network provider name is invalid.

[OK]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Machine info:
windows7 professional sp1 x64
Intel 82583V Gigabit Network Card

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah ha I found the answer!

Adobe Drive 4 had somehow messed up my system. The Network Provider Order only listed "AdobeDrive4".  So I edited the key to add back the default providers.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\HwOrder]
"ProviderOrder"="AdobeDrive4,RDPNP,LanmanWorkstation,webclient"
```

Fixed.

Comment: Had the same issue including not being able to use the `Map Network Drive` feature in Windows Explorer. I was able to navigate to network folders and files via `cmd` and manually map drives using `subst UNC-PATH`. Resolution was the same. I extracted the `HwOrder` and `Order`settings to a .reg file from a different (working) PC and imported that into my PC. After reboot, everything works again. Not sure how this got corrupted, but I had been testing out new memory and had a few BSODs just prior to this. Thanks!